# Account (un)merge glitch

Tags: bug, merge-accounts

Two days ago, a particular user was causing a lot of trouble on Meta and Mathematics. They were merged with [Eggs McLaren](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152055/stackexchangeisunfair2) probably due to a mistake, then merged with another account, before being unmerged and presumably destroyed. However, they still remain on [Mathematics meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1199903/stackexchangeisunfair2), and from the profile the account still appears to be merged with Eggs.

Looking at the communities on Eggs profile, I wasn't able to find Mathematics but that is probably because only the meta account remains. However, the profile has some [achievements](https://stackexchange.com/users/6/eggs-mclaren?tab=activity) related to the spam incident, confirming that the accounts are still somewhat merged.

Tldr; spammer -> merged with Eggs -> merged with other user -> unmerged, but Mathematics meta account still merged with Eggs

Presumably the account has truly been merged with Eggs, i.e. it effectively belongs to Jeff now(not to say that he was involved but that the account was truly merged), as the user has created a [new account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1389496/stackexchangeisunfair2), and was given a century-long suspension.

Comment: Well at least they didn't merge it with Jeff actual account, or random account of actual user, who would wonder how they became a troll out of the blue. Critical mistake on SE side, pity they're not transparent about it.

Comment: What do you mean "effectively belongs to Jeff "?? I read it as if Jeff is involved, which I find hard to believe. Changed my vote according to it. (While Jeff appears to be against some of the new company decisions and policy, I can't imagine he'll become a troll.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack since Eggs McLaren is Jeff's sock puppet, and the troll account is still somehow merged with Eggs, I found out that it has been truly merged; i.e.  Jeff is now the only one that can access it by logging into the account. I'm not saying that he was involved.

Comment: I've added clarification to avoid confusion.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear to me what the point of making a Meta post about this is. Is this simply informational, or is there some action you want someone to take? Could you clarify?

Comment: @JonathanZonstrike it's a glitch, so I assume the goal is to have it fixed, i.e. remove any trace of the offensive account from the non-offensive account.

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought that would be something you just contact the mods about, but I don't really know the ins-and-outs of stuff like this.

Comment: @JonathanZonstrike mods can't (un)merge accounts, only staff can.